# Eclipse and m2e - test classpath

Tags: eclipse, testing, maven, classpath, m2e

I have Spring project backed up by maven and I am using m2e plugin. Now, some of my files are in the `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` folder. Now, the problem is that when I am running tests some of the .xml files with configuration don't work because paths to the resources are breaking.

Firstly, question. When I do on project `Run As -> JUnit test`, dose eclipse backs up by doing `mvn test`, or is it maven agnostic this way? If so this would explain why after adding

```
<plugin> 
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <additionalClasspathElements>
      <additionalClasspathElement>/src/main/webapp/</additionalClasspathElement>
    </additionalClasspathElements>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

to my `pom.xml` when I run the test using `Run As -> JUnit test` and printing classpath I am not seeing my added location, but doing `mvn test` I can see this location added to classpath.

So, is it possible to make eclipse/maven copy some additional files to `target/classes` or `target/test-classes`

or

just add some folders to the runtime classpath when testing the applcation.

Also, is it possible to do such thing in one place so it does not matter if I am running tests using Eclipse gui or just `mvn test` from console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this has changed recently, your class path in eclipse is still built from your .classpath file.
m2e injects some elements, notably dependencies, but source/resource paths still  need an entry.

Adding what you need to your .classpath should solve the issue.

Comment: Ok, but also I would need to add appropriate entries to pom.xml so I can run my tests using console maven?